# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Стоит задача:
После загрузки страницы проверить подключен ли jQuery, загрузить его в случае недоступности. После этого вызвать функцию `myfunc` на jQuery.

```
function myfunc() {
    jQuery("<myselector>").contents();
};
if (window.jQuery) {
    myfunc();
} else {
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = function() { setTimeout(myfunc, 3000); };
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

В консоли Google Chrome запускаю этот код для загруженной страницы.
Получаю в ответ ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Почему возникает ошибка? Ведь вызов функции `myfunc` я делаю после полной загрузки страницы и загрузки `jquery.min.js`, да еще и с задержкой 3 сек. Причем в некоторых случаях загрузки одного и того же сайта эта ошибка не возникает.

Тестировал на сайте techcrunc.

Comment: в конце body скрипт добавлен? у меня данная корнструкция работает

Comment: я запускаю этот код через консоль браузера вручную, после загрузки самой страницы